# How to do a simple unit testing with RabbitMQ in python?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

In my unit test, I want to simply start consuming, publish a message, and receive a response back and assert if the response is what I expect it to be. However, I have been trying to do this for hours and don't find a solution.

The problem is that I cannot define a method in a class that stops the consuming. I have tried defining a method like this:

```
def stop(self):
    self.channel.basic_cancel()
```

```
def stop(self):
    self.channel.stop_consuming()
```

```
def stop(self):
    self.connection.close()
```

But nothing seems to work. I have read that this is because once you execute `start_consuming()`, the only way to stop the consuming is to cancel it after a message is sent. But if I do this, then I would be modifying the original `on_request` and that wouldn't be useful for my application, because the connection will close after the first message. I have found [pytest-rabbitmq](https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-rabbitmq) but the documentation isn't clear for me and thus don't know if I can use this plugin to achieve what I want.

By the way, what is the difference between `basic_cancel`, `stop_consuming` and `close`?

Comment: @Peter Sorry if you have that impression, but StackOverflow says that comments should not be cluttered with "thank you"s, but rather accepting an answer as the correct one is the way to go. It's not that I am impolite, it's what StackOverflow says to do so. However, when I can, I say thank you + something substantial. And regarding helping others, I would love to, but I don't have the knowledge you have to answer 99.9% of the questions asked here. I have my own YouTube channel and Discord server where I help people in what I can about programming. Sorry for being too "average".

Answer (score 2):

I am not getting a clear idea of your scenario!. With my understanding, you can create the connection and channel in the same method so that you can publish, consumer, assert and stop the consume when needed

Hope this helps!

```
def test_rabbitmq():
    from pika import BlockingConnection, ConnectionParameters, PlainCredentials

    conn = BlockingConnection(ConnectionParameters(host='host', virtual_host='vhost', credentials=PlainCredentials('username', 'password')))
    channel = conn.channel()

    # define your consumer
    def on_message(channel, method_frame, header_frame, body):
        message = body.decode()
        # assert your message here
        # asset message == 'value'
        channel.basic_cancel('test-consumer')  # stops the consumer

    # define your publisher
    def publish_message(message):
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='', body=message')

    publish('your message')
    tag = channel.basic_consume(queue='queue', on_message_callback=on_message, consumer_tag='test-consumer')
```

`stop_consuming` - Cancels all consumers, signalling the start_consuming loop to exit.

`basic_cancel` - This method cancels a consumer. A consumer tag will be taken as input.

`close` - Closes the connection/channel

[Reference](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the [pytest-rabbitmq](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-rabbitmq/) plugin:

```py
import asyncio
import rabbitpy


async def test_queue(fastapi_client, mocker, rabbitmq):
    mock_consumer_method = mocker.MagicMock(name="consumer_method")
    mocker.patch(
        "my.project.consumer_method",
        new=mock_consumer_method,
    )

    connection_details = rabbitmq.args
    os.environ[
        "RABBITMQ_CONNECTION_STRING"
    ] = f"amqp://{connection_details['username']}:{connection_details['password']}@{connection_details['host']}:{connection_details['port']}/"  # this is used by my consumer

    channel = rabbitmq.channel()
    queue = rabbitpy.Queue(
        channel, name="QUEUE_NAME", durable=False, message_ttl=5 * 60 * 1000
    )
    queue.declare()
    message = rabbitpy.Message(channel, "some message")
    message.publish(exchange="", routing_key=PRODUCE_QUEUE_NAME)

    with fastapi_client:  # triggers the consumer startup event
        await asyncio.sleep(20)

    mock_consumer_method.assert_called_once_with("some message")
```

I already have a consumer as part of my FastAPI server, your use case might be different.